# show that $f$ is Ergodic with respect of Lebesgue measure.

Tags: ergodic-theory

If $f:[0,1]\to [0,1]$ is given by

$$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
        2x                & \mbox{ if  }   x\in [0,1/3)\\
                          &                           \\
2x-\frac{2}{3}  & \mbox{ if  }   x\in [1/3,1/2)\\
2x-\frac{1}{3}          & \mbox{ if  }   x\in [1/2,2/3)\\
                          &                           \\
2x-1  & \mbox{ if  }   x\in [2/3,1]
\end{cases}
$$
show that $f$ is Ergodic with respect of Lebesgue measure.

The idea is to try to show that given an invariant set of positive measure, this set will have full measure.

A very common process is to partition the domain, choose a point of density in the invariant set, use the the Lebesgue Density Theorem and the bounded distortion property

\begin{align*}
\dfrac{m(f^k(E_1))}{m(f^k(E_2))}=\dfrac{m(E_1)}{m(E_2)}
\end{align*}.

I have several questions. In this case, how should I partition the set? Should I use the iterates of f to form the partition in the domain? Or do not you? What would her iterations look like? What are the conditions for using the motto of limited distortion?